# PYTHON:: How to send HTTP Request/Response using "urllib2" from different source MAC and IP address

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, urllib2, urllib

I am using curl to authenticate a login session in my company website. following is the curl command that I am using:

```
curl -g -v --interface wlan0 -k --user-agent Mozilla/5.0 --url http://10.0.0.2:880/cgi-bin/hslogin.cgi \ -d "f_user=abc3&f_pass=test3&f_hs_server=10.10.10.1&f_Qv=it_qpmjdz=blbti_dbqujwf@bbb_qpmjdz=blbti_bbb@dmjfou_njou=537:71687@dmjfou_nbd=35.88.14.5F.:5.81@ttje=dbqujwf234@bq_nbd=C5.D8.::.83.F7.D1&agree=yes&submit=Log+In"
```

I am able to create one login session using the above curl script.

Since I need to create multiple login sessions, I am trying to modify above curl script using python script.

```
import urllib2
data = '{"nw_src": "10.0.0.1/32", "nw_dst": "10.0.0.2/32", "nw_proto": "ICMP", "actions": "ALLOW", "priority": "10"}'
url = 'http://<IP ADDRESS>:880/cgi-bin/hslogin.cgi'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
for x in f:
print(x)
f.close()
```

How to specify "Source MAC address(a3:11:b7:25:34:a5)", "Source IP address (10.0.0.1)", "Username (abc3) and Password (test3)" in the above script.

Comment: Hello friend, do you know the meaning of each of the url parameters? I'm developing a solution where i have to decode all these parameters, but i did not know where can i get the users mac address and other data. Can you help me please? Thanks!